# Jacoco and Sonar scanning giving different results

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan, jacoco-maven-plugin

So when I execute *mvn clean verify* my code coverage is 64% for lines coverage and 62% for branch coverage. But in sonarqube my code coverage is 70%:
[image]
Where is that difference coming from? I do not exclude any classes either in Jacobo or Sonar and I use the same branch here end there.
This are my snapshots from pom:

```
    <jacoco.version>0.8.8</jacoco.version>
    <properties-maven-plugin.version>1.1.0</properties-maven-plugin.version>
    <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.9.1.2184</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>60%</minimum>
                            </limit>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>60%</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>coverage-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>coverage-report</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>coverage-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


     <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.V_TEMPLATE_TYPE</name>
                <value>CI</value>
            </property>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${properties-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>sonar.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sonar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Another thing is, that when I add exclusions then for sonar they affect the result, but for Jacobo their result remains the same. I tried to put  in various places in code below, with most logical option for me as between /limits and /rule, but with no effect at all:

```
             <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <rule>
                            <element>BUNDLE</element>
                            <limits>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>LINE</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>70%</minimum>
                                </limit>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>70%</minimum>
                                </limit>
                            </limits>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
```

I also have sonar.properties which I've added directly for GitHub and Sonar integration (just sonar scan was configured in pom, which remains till now) in which I have:

```
sonar.projectKey=
sonar.projectName=
sonar.host.url=
sonar.login=
sonar.exclusions=OPTIONAL
```

Comment: What kind of sonar.properites are needed and how do they look like? What has been configured in sonar.properties?

Comment: sonar.projectKey=
sonar.projectName=
sonar.host.url=
sonar.login=
sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/com/.../.../

Comment: Why do you have exclusions in your configuration? Which you don't have here configured in jacoco? Apart from that why has the sonar plugin bound to the life cycle? Usually sonar plugin is called via goal....

Comment: I do have it but it is not working at all so I removed it in the snapshot as they are not working. I had them before </rules> but they didn't affect the result at all. As to the second thing you wrote, I don't get it, could you explain a bit? Where do I have life cycle? I do use goal

Comment: In the profile `sonar` you have bound sonar plugin to the life cycle... if you even use goal `sonar:sonar` that means you can remove that configuration....

Answer (score 0):

The "Coverage" value that SonarQube produces is not simple line coverage.  It is computed by a formula that includes several terms.  This page shows the algorithm: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-and-code-coverage/4725#how-to-calculate-code-coverage-4 .